# How to plot Reuleaux triangle in rectangular coordinates?

Tags: plotting

I need to plot the [Reuleaux triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) in rectangular coordinates.

[image: Reuleaux triangle]

I am not sure if there's a Reuleaux triangle equation.  If yes, I can plot it by `ContourPlot`.

I saw [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReuleauxTriangle.html) but I just need curve of Reuleaux triangle.

What's the best way to plot a Reuleaux triangle?

Comment: The Reuleaux triangle has sharp corners, so `ContourPlot` would have problems to draw that.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Who cares!  What if I want to built it in Minecraft and just want an approximation?

Comment: @Michael The more distuebing question is: Who cares more than 5 years laters?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Obviously content on the internet is not just swept away a few months after it is created because it continues to have value to people in the future, often in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A long time ago, I derived [parametric equations for Reuleaux polygons](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/parametric-equations-for-regular-and-reuleaux-polygons/).

Specializing the formulae in that post to the triangle case, we have

```
ParametricPlot[{(Sqrt[3] Cos[π/6 (2 SawtoothWave[u] - 1)] - 1) Cos[π/3 (2 Floor[u] + 1)] -
                Sqrt[3] Sin[π/6 (2 SawtoothWave[u] - 1)] Sin[π/3 (2 Floor[u] + 1)],
                Sqrt[3] Cos[π/3 (2 Floor[u] + 1)] Sin[π/6 (2 SawtoothWave[u] - 1)] +
                (Sqrt[3] Cos[π/6 (2 SawtoothWave[u] - 1)] - 1) Sin[π/3 (2 Floor[u] + 1)]},
               {u, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Reuleaux triangle]

---

After some prompting by Jens, I tried looking again for a polar representation of the Reuleaux triangle. I finally managed to find one, but it is not very pretty:

```
PolarPlot[Cos[Mod[θ, 2 π/3, 2 π/3]] + Sqrt[2 + Cos[Mod[θ, 2 π/3, 2 π/3]]^2],
          {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Reuleaux triangle]

Comment: I'd be curious if there's a simple form that could be used with `PolarPlot`. Probably not... but maybe you've thought about it.

Comment: @Jens, I haven't found one, but definitely not for lack of trying.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if the best but here is one way:

```
RegionIntersection @@ (Disk /@ CirclePoints[1/Sqrt[3], 3]) // 
RegionBoundary // 
Region
```

[image]

Comment: I am impressed with the simplicity of your solution !

Comment: @yarchik thanks, yes one can get lazy with Mathematica